# Creating my own SQL Connection pool, wondering if this is bad practice / has faults?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, pool

So I created my own MySQL Connection Pool using a Blocking Queue filled with a list of SQLConnection objects:

```
public class SQLConnection {

private Connection connection;
private int uses;
private long alive;

protected SQLConnection() {
    try {
        this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(SQLPool.URL, SQLPool.USER, SQLPool.PASS);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.uses = 0;
    this.alive = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

protected void addUse() {
    uses++;
}

protected boolean isRenew() {
    try {
        if (connection.isClosed() || uses > 100 || getAlive() > 900000) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

protected boolean isAvailable() {
    try {
        return !connection.isClosed();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

The pool, (code not shown) has a retrieveResource() and returnResource(SQLConnection conn) method, as well as, the BlockingQueue. It seems to work perfectly, and after it's alive time is above 15 mins or it has 100 uses, it gets dumped from the pool and a new instance is added.
Since my project has to be very solid, I was wondering if there were any obvious issues that arise with this?

Comment: There are already many solid database connection pool libraries you can use off the shelf. Why create a new one that is most likely faulty? I mean, those libraries are at this point time-tested. Just to name one, you can use the "free and for free" DBCP from Apache.

Comment: Okay @TheImpaler will do, cheers.